# getting grails 2.0.0M1 config info in domain object, and static scope?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

How do I get to the Config.groovy information  from a domain object, or from a static scope? I'm using ConfigurationHolder.config.* now, but that and ApplicationHolder are deprecated so I'd like to 'do it right' ... but the grailsApplication object isn't available in a DO/static scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd add the `grailsApplication` to the metaclass of domain classes - this is something I'm thinking about doing for 2.0 final. For now, put it in `BootStrap.groovy`, e.g.

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      for (dc in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
         dc.clazz.metaClass.getGrailsApplication = { -> grailsApplication }
         dc.clazz.metaClass.static.getGrailsApplication = { -> grailsApplication }
      }      
   }
}
```

Then you can access the config from `grailsApplication.config`, and Spring beans via `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('foo')` or just `grailsApplication.mainContext.foo`.

Comment: Good idea ... but, startup fails with "Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectqdcore.UserCallFlow" (qdcore.UserCallFlow is a domain class), as it appears Hibernate is doing something before the Bootstrap runs. To get around that, I use safe deref (e.g., grailsApplication?.config?.qdcore?.servers?.upload?.url ) so that Hibernate is happy, the Bootstrap gets to run, and then grailsApplication is available. Thanks!

Comment: But, even with safe deref in the DO (def grailsApplication; def config=grailsApplication?.config; def String usrv = config?.qdcore?.servers?.upload?.url) I'm getting null values, so I'm not using it right, quite yet - I'll post back when I get myself sorted out ;)

Comment: What works in the DO is to use the static scope for grailsApplication, and the instance scope for the rest; e.g.,class UCF { static grailsApplication; def config=grailsApplication?.config; def String usrv = config?.qdcore?.servers?.upload?.url ...} I can't use static scope for the others, since then I get exceptions that "grailsApplication" is null when I try to get its config property. This is a bit twitchy, perhaps, but it works for this prototyping app!

Comment: Burt, please do include grailApplication in DCs in Grails 2.0, would be a convenient, concise, & useful addition

Comment: @Burt Beckwith, is the `grails.util.Holders` method, mentioned by Ian Roberts, the new preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 19):

The Grails 2 replacement for the deprecated `ApplicationHolder`, `ConfigurationHolder`, etc. is [`grails.util.Holders`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html), which provides the same functionality but in a way that is safe when several different webapps in the same container are sharing a single copy of the Grails JARs in a parent classloader (this being the case where the old holders broke down).

```
import grails.util.Holders

// ...

static void foo() {
  def configOption = Holders.config.myapp.option
}
```

Comment: This was particularly helpful in the static triggers block of quartz scheduled jobs. Thanks!

Comment: This is also working in the hibernate mappings in domain to have thing configurable from external properties file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted to access config in static utilities only. After searching and reading most of the answers on SO, i came with simple solution(May be useful for somebody):

Add holder class under src/groovy:

```
class StaticContext {
    static def app;
}
```

initialize it in bootstrap init

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
      StaticContext.app = grailsApplication
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

And access it in static utilities :

```
//In my case Solr URL in single ton
def solrUrl = StaticContext.app.config.solr.url
```

Answer (score 1):

In Grails 2.2.5 I found this would work:

1. Configure your variable in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`, in the section appropiate for your environment. For example:

   ```
   environments {
   ...
     development {
     ...
       grails.config.myUrl = "http://localhost:3000"
       ...
   ```

   ...
2. To access:

   ```
   import grails.util.Holders

   class myClass {
   ...

      def static myStaticMethod() {
         def myVar = Holders.config.grails.config.myUrl
   ...
   ```