# Grails - access static config object in codec class

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am currently updating my Grails project in order not to use the deprecated ConfigurationHolder class.
This goes fine in most cases, but I am facing trouble in my custom codec classes, where I have been using the following approach until now:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH
class MyCodec {

    static boolean myStaticConfigProperty=CH.config.myStaticConfigProperty

    static encode = { something ->
       if(myStaticConfigProperty)
          ...
    }

}
```

Direct injection using

```
def grailsApplication
```

does not work in this case since this will be injected as a non-static object.

Instead I have tried to use the approach suggested in this post [getting-grails-2-0-0m1-config-info-in-domain-object-and-static-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976983/getting-grails-2-0-0m1-config-info-in-domain-object-and-static-scope), but I cannot make it work even after injecting the grailsApplication object into my codec metaclasses in the bootstrap:

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      for (cc in grailsApplication.codecClasses) {
         cc.clazz.metaClass.getGrailsApplication = { -> grailsApplication }
         cc.clazz.metaClass.static.getGrailsApplication = { -> grailsApplication }
      }      
   }
}
```

Could anyone suggest an approach that will allow me to access the config object in a static way inside codec classes?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like this completely untested code:

```
class MyCodec {

    static def grailsConfig

    static boolean myStaticConfigProperty = grailsConfig.myStaticConfigProperty

    static encode = { something ->
       if(myStaticConfigProperty)
          ...
    }

}

class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      for (cc in grailsApplication.codecClasses) {
         cc.grailsConfig = grailsApplication.config 
      }      
   }
}
```

If all of your codec classes just need the same one configuration property, you could skip injecting the grailsApplication and/or the config object entirely, and just set the one static property from BootStrap.

Comment: I tried your approach, but it does not seem to work. I believe the reason is that the MyCodec obejct is initialised before the Bootstrap.init() is run. Thereby the line
    
"static boolean myStaticConfigProperty = grailsConfig.myStaticConfigProperty"

seems to be the reason for failing.

Comment: So, you're probably going to have to make the property non-static. Here's an example that looks like it does what you want. http://www.zorched.net/2008/02/03/encryption-codecs-and-unit-tests-in-grails/

Comment: A bit late at following up. I tried your suggested approach, but could not make it work. Ended up using this approach instead. It works:http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993

Answer (score 1):

it works for me in grails 2.2.3

```
import grails.util.Holders as holders;

class MyFileCodec {
    static encode = {file ->
        def configPath= holders.grailsApplication.config.share.contextPath
        return "${configPath}/${file.name}"
    }
}
```

[grails.util.Holders](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.1/api/grails/util/Holders.html) has been introduced since grails 2.0, it's the way to access config object.