# Using grails configuration values in domain object constraints

Tags: unit-testing, grails, config, domain-object

Grails 2.2.0

How do I access the custom configuration variables in a Grails domain object constraints.

I would like to have something like this:

```
    class User {

         def grailsApplication

         String name

         static constraints = {
             name size: grailsApplication.config.maxlength
         }  

    }
```

But it fails with "No such property: grailsApplication". I have tried to get it work by following suggestions in [getting grails 2.0.0M1 config info in domain object, and static scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976983/getting-grails-2-0-0m1-config-info-in-domain-object-and-static-scope) but have not managed to get any combination to work.

How do I access config in domain object constraints? In addition how do I handle such a case in a unit test for the domain constraints?

Comment: Did you try `this.grailsApplication...` ?

Comment: Holders.getGrailsApplication().config.maxlength

Comment: @SérgioMichels or even shorter: Holders.config.maxlength

Comment: @codelark You should make that comment an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: If the Config.groovy has "grails.myvar = 10" then using "name minSize: Holders.config.grails.myvar" in domain constraint works. Both integration and unit tests. @codelark make an answer to accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `grails.util.Holders` class to get access to the configuration object as follows:

In `Config.groovy`:

```
myMaxSize = 10
```

In your domain class:

```
class User {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name minSize: Holders.config.myMaxSize
    }
}
```